# Stored procedure - Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

When running a simple stored procedure, I'm getting this error and frankly I don't know why.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure PROC_TEST, Line 15
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Columns:

- `SI_ID` is `NUMERIC(19,0)`
- `SI_COMPANYID` is `NUMERIC(19,0)`
- `SI_LOGINID` is `VARCHAR(100)`

Any idea why?

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [xxxxxx].[PROC_TEST] 
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE
          @id NUMERIC(19,0),
          @login VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR       <<----- Line 15
    FOR
       SELECT 
           SI_ID, SI_LOGINID 
       FROM SI_USER 
       WHERE SI_COMPANYID = 123

    OPEN user_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor into @id, @login

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
          PRINT @id + ', ' + @login

          FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor into @id, @login
    END

    CLOSE user_cursor
    DEALLOCATE user_cursor
END
```

Comment: What is type of column `SI_COMPANYID`?

Comment: @Parado SI_COMPANYID is NUMERIC(19,0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL error line reference is inaccurate. 
The error seems to be this line: `PRINT @id + ', ' + @login`

Try `PRINT CONVERT(varchar, @id) + ', ' + @login`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed the issue. Can't believe I've squandered several hours on a stupid thing like this just because Microsoft is not able to provide a precise error message. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Parado, don't worry I always accept answer. Just have to wait 3 more minutes to accept it (can't do it right now, the system prevent accepting answers too quickly)